# what is the significance of `__repr__` function over normal function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to learn python with my own and i stucked at `__repr__` function. Though i have read lots of post on `__repr__` along with the python document. so i have decided to ask this Question here. The code bellow explains my confusion.

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self,x,y):
            self.x, self.y = x,y

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point(x=%s, y=%s)'%(self.x, self.y)

    def print_class(self):
        return 'Point(x=%s, y=%s)'%(self.x, self.y)



p = Point(1,2)

print p
print p.print_class()


Point(x=1, y=2)
Point(x=1, y=2)
```

If a normal function can also perform  similar task then what is the extra advantage of `__repr__` over `print_class()` (in my case a normal function) function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `__repr__` function is called by `repr()` internally. `repr()` is called when you are printing the object directly , and the class does not define a `__str__()` . From [documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

> **object.__repr__(self)**
>
> Called by the repr() built-in function and by string conversions (reverse quotes) to compute the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form <...some useful description...> should be returned. The return value must be a string object. If a class defines `__repr__()` but not `__str__()`, then `__repr__()` is also used when an “informal” string representation of instances of that class is required.

In your case for `print_class()`  , you have to specifically call the method when printing the object. But in case of `__repr__()` , it gets internally called by `print` .

This is especially useful, when you are mixing different classes/types . For Example lets take a list which can have numbers and objects of your `point` class, now you want to print the elements of the list.

If you do not define the `__repr__()` or `__str__()` , you would have to first check the instance , whether its of type `Point` if so call `print_class()` , or if not directly print the number.

But when your class defines the `__repr__()` or `__str__()` , you can just directly call `print` on all the elements of the list, `print` statement would internally take care of printing the correct values.

Example , Lets assume a class which has `print_class()` method, but no `__repr__()` or `__str__()` , code -

```
>>> class CA:
...     def __init__(self,x):
...             self.x = x
...     def print_class(self):
...             return self.x
...
>>> l = [1,2,3,CA(4),CA(5)]
>>> for i in l:
...     print(i)
...
1
2
3
<__main__.CA object at 0x00590F10>
<__main__.CA object at 0x005A5070>
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> for i in l:
...     if isinstance(i, CA):
...             print(i.print_class())
...     else:
...             print(i)
...
1
2
3
4
5
```

As you can see, when we mix numbers and objects of type `CA` in the list, and then when we just did `print(i)` , it did not print what we wanted. For this to work correctly, we had to check the type of `i` and call the appropriate method (as done in second case).

Now lets assume a class that implements `__repr__()` instead of `print_class()` -

```
>>> class CA:
...     def __init__(self,x):
...             self.x = x
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return str(self.x)
...
>>>
>>> l = [1,2,3,CA(4),CA(5)]
>>> for i in l:
...     print(i)
...
1
2
3
4
5
```

As you can see in second case, simply printing worked, since `print` internally calls `__str__()` first, and as that did not exist fell back to `__repr__()` .

And not just this, when we do `str(list)` , internally each list's element's `__repr__()` is called. Example -

First case (without `__repr__()` ) -

```
>>> str(l)
'[1, 2, 3, <__main__.CA object at 0x005AB3D0>, <__main__.CA object at 0x005AB410>]'
```

Second case (with `__repr__()` ) -

```
>>> str(l)
'[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'
```

---

Also, in interactive interpreter, when you are directly using the object, it shows you the output of `repr()` function, Example -

```
>>> class CA:
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return "CA instance"
...
>>>
>>> c = CA()
>>> c
CA instance
```

Comment: Can You explain your 3, 4 and 5th (mixing different classes/types --) comment with example code. Thanks for all your explanation

Comment: Ok sure, let me update it.

Comment: Updated the answer with detailed examples.

Comment: Great explanation and thanks a lot for all you effort.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the `__repr__` function is automatically called by Python in certain contexts, and is part of a predefined API with specific requirements.  For instance, if you enter `p` by itself(not `print p`) in the interactive shell after creating your `p` object, its `__repr__` will be called.  It will also be used for `print p` if you don't define a `__str__`on `p`.  (That is, you had to write `print p.print_class()`, but you didn't have to write `print p.__repr__()`; Python called `__repr__` automatically for you.)  The requirements for `__repr__` are described in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__):

> Called by the repr() built-in function and by string conversions (reverse quotes) to compute the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form <...some useful description...> should be returned.

In short, if you write your own method called `print_class` you can make it do whatever you want and tell people how to use it, because it's your API.  If you use `__repr__` you're supposed to follow the conventions of Python's API.  Either one may make sense depending on the context.

Comment: @BrenBam So it means that  i can write a function or method equivalent to __repr__ if i dont want to use it or is there any task that cant be done/assume  without __repr__ function .

Comment: thanks for explaining

Comment: @jax: You can write your own method, yes.

Answer (score 0):

It helps you do more efficient coding work. even though you get same result using user define method like 'print_class()' as **repr**, but you don't need to type in '.print_class()' by **repr** method.